# Realization and Tensor Product of Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

Let V & W are complex vector spaces of dimensions m and n respectively, I want to ask how does realization behaves with the tensor product of vector spaces, more precisely $\\$Can we say that "the realization of the tensor product is same as the tensor product of realized vector spaces? " i.e$$(V\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} W)_{\mathbb{R}}\cong V_{\mathbb{R}}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} W_{\mathbb{R}}$$

Intuitively looks like it might not be true, considering the dimensions don't match (dim LHS=2mn$\neq$4mn=dim RHS).
But since the dimension is exactly half in the LHS, we might expect something more i.e

1. Whether there is an isomorphism for 2 copies of LHS (as direct sum) to the RHS.
2. Whether there is some relation between them in any other way possible.

Kindly help! Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural relationship here is that there is a quotient map $V_{\mathbb{R}}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} W_{\mathbb{R}}\to (V\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} W)_{\mathbb{R}}$.  Indeed, note that the map $\mu:V_\mathbb{R}\times W_\mathbb{R}\to (V\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} W)_{\mathbb{R}}$ defined by $\mu(v,w)=v\otimes w$ is $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear, so by the universal property of the tensor product it gives an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $f:V_{\mathbb{R}}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} W_{\mathbb{R}}\to (V\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} W)_{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $f(v\otimes w)=v\otimes w$ (note that the "$v\otimes w$" on the two sides here are not the same thing; on the left side it is an element of the tensor product over $\mathbb{R}$ and on the right side it is an element of the tensor product over $\mathbb{C}$).  To see that this $f$ is surjective, note that $V\otimes_\mathbb{C} W$ is generated as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space by elements of the form $v\otimes w$, and therefore is actually also generated as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space by such elements since $i(v\otimes w)=(iv)\otimes w$.

Another way to think of this is that to form the tensor product, you take formal linear combinations of elements of the form $v\otimes w$ and then impose relations saying that $\otimes$ is a bilinear operation.  The relations that say $\otimes$ is $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear are a subset of the relations that say $\otimes$ is $\mathbb{C}$-bilinear.  So you could construct the tensor product over $\mathbb{C}$ by first imposing the $\mathbb{R}$-bilinearity relations to get the tensor product over $\mathbb{R}$, and then imposing further relations make $\otimes$ actually $\mathbb{C}$-bilinear and get the tensor product over $\mathbb{C}$.  (Note that over $\mathbb{C}$ you have more formal linear combinations than over $\mathbb{R}$, but this doesn't actually give you any new elements in the tensor product over $\mathbb{C}$ since bilinearity forces $i(v\otimes w)=(iv)\otimes w$.)  So, the tensor product over $\mathbb{C}$ is a quotient of the tensor product over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Wow, now I can recall Universality was the main property that my professor asked me to apply whenever tackling Tensor Product, just one thing why are you calling the map f , quotient map , Is it equivalent to saying that by first isomorpshism theoremn quotienting by Kernel gives me the isomorpshism?@EricWofsey

Comment: Can you explain this line also "since $i(v\otimes w)=(iv)\otimes w$."@EricWofsey

Comment: If you have a $\mathbb{C}$-linear combination of elements of the form $v\otimes w$, you can turn it into an $\mathbb{R}$-linear combination by splitting each of the coefficients into their real and imaginary parts and then absorbing the $i$ of the imaginary part into the tensor using $i(v\otimes w)=(iv)\otimes w$.  (Alternatively, you could just absorb the entire coefficients into the tensor to see that every element is actually just a *sum* of elements of the form $v\otimes w$).